# MultiValueDictKeyError while uploading a media file(.mp4) through Django REST API POST Call

Tags: python, django, file-upload, django-rest-framework

I am new to Django REST Framework. I have created an API which takes a MP4 file as an input, processes it and gives a response. I am able to upload file through API browser page and get the result. However, when i am trying to call the API through a local python file i get the following error:

> MultiValueDictKeyError at /api/ 'file'
>
> Request Method: POST

**API call:**

```
import requests
import json
url = 'http://182.xx.xx.xx:8000/api/'
video_file = '/home/lueinuser/Downloads/original.mp4' # 30 MB file in my Local system
payload = {'file' : video_file}
r = requests.post(url=url,data=payload)
print(r.text)
```

**Views.py**

```
class ApiCallingListView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = ApiCallingModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ApiCallingSerializer
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)

    def post(self, request, format=None, *args, **kwargs):
        file_serializer = ApiCallingSerializer(data=request.data)
        file = request.FILES['file']
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        filename = fs.save(file.name, file)
        uploaded_file_url = settings.MEDIA_ROOT  + '/' + str(filename)
        data_dict = {'video_file': request.FILES}
        request.data['response']= api_wrapper(uploaded_file_url)

        if file_serializer.is_valid():
            file_serializer.save()
            return Response(file_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(file_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**Models.py**

```
class ApiCallingModel(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(blank=False, null=False)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    response = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending the file correctly:

```
video_file = '/home/lueinuser/Downloads/original.mp4' # this is just a string, not the content of the file
```

You need to `open` a file like this:

```
video_file = open('/home/lueinuser/Downloads/original.mp4','rb')
```

And call `request.post` with `files` named argument, not as `data`:

```
video_file = open('/home/lueinuser/Downloads/original.mp4','rb')
files = {'file': video_file}
r = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

See [docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file)